# Is it possible to change the spacing between files using ls

Tags: ls

I'm fairly new to unix and I was wondering if there's some attribute of `ls` that I can use to change the spacing between the files. Currently I've aliased my `ls` to output `ls -G`, so that I have colored folders. However, the downside of that is that the files/folders show up a little more squooshed/close together.

Comment: What does option `-G` have to do with colours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to fix this by either running `ls -G -T1`, (or --tabsize=1 instead of -T1), or set TABSIZE=1 in your ~/.bashrc.

Comment: @Amit, can you please explain how this answer solved your problem?

Comment: this does not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ls -G` does spacing any differently than `ls`.

The width depends on how long the file names are in each directory.

Try running `/bin/ls` and `/bin/ls -G` in the same directory, and you should notice the spacing is the same.

Then change to a different directory and try it again.

The other possibility is that you are seeing the difference between columns (`-C`) and across (`-x`) mode.

Try running `ls -C` and `ls -x` and see which one you prefer.

Then make it an alias.

Comment: I see, thanks for the suggestion!, I'll try it! and mark as correct if it helps!